# How to add text from textbox in angularjs1

Tags: angularjs

I have written a code for adding messages to the page below the textbox. The text box has an add button . As soon i write a message in the textbx and click on add, the message should appear on the next line. I have used ng-repeat to repeat  the process of adding messages whenever the add button is clicked. However i am getting error messages - 
     Expression 'addMessage()' is non-assignable. 
     And Error -
    angular.js:13283 ReferenceError: message is not defined.
 Please help me with the code.

```
<html ng-app="Swabhav.Message">

<head>
  <title>message-app</title>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="MessageAdd">
  <h3>To Add Message:</h3>
  <input text="text" ng-model="addMessage()">
  <li ng-repeat="mess in message">
    <button type="button" ng-click="addMessage()">Add</button>
  </li>

  <br>
  <li><p> {{mess}}</li>
  </p><br>

</div>

<script>

  angular.module("Swabhav.Message", [])
    .controller("MessageAdd", ["$scope", function($scope) {

      $scope.message = [];

      $scope.addMessage = function() {
        $scope.message.push(message);
      };
    }]);

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MessageAdd">
    <h3>To Add Message:</h3>
    <input text="text" ng-model="messagetext">
    <button type="button" ng-click="addMessage()">Add</button>
    <li ng-repeat="mess in message">{{mess}}</li>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
angular.module("Swabhav.Message",[])
.controller("MessageAdd",["$scope",function($scope){
  $scope.messagetext = "";
  $scope.message=[];
  $scope.addMessage =function(){
    $scope.message.push($scope.messagetext);
    $scope.messagetext = "";
  }
}]);
```

Comment: now i want to add the message when enter key is pressed. I deleted the button tag and <input type="text"  ng-keypress="addMessage($event)"  ng-model="message"> And added an if statement in the function ->$scope.addMessage=function($event){
                                     if($event.which==13){
                                  
                                    $scope.messages.push($scope.message);
                                     }. Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors.

First, you can't assign a function to a model. You have to add te value on your model to the array of messages. Then your button has to be before the ng-repeat or you will have one botton for each element on the list and {{mess}} inside the ng-repeat.

```
 <input text="text" ng-model="message">
       <button type="button" ng-click="addMessage()">Add</button>
       <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="mess in messages">
            {{mess}}
        </li>  
       </ul>
```

In your controller I would rename the array to messages and assign a empty array to your model.

```
$scope.messages=[];
$scope.message = "";

$scope.addMessage =function(){
  $scope.messages.push($scope.message);
  $scope.message = "";
}
```

Try this code and tell me if it is what you are trying to do and if you understand the code

[Jsfddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfmh5ryx/4/)

Comment: now i want to add the message when enter key is pressed. I deleted the button tag and <input type="text"  ng-keypress="addMessage($event)"  ng-model="message"> And added an if statement in the function ->$scope.addMessage=function($event){
                                     if($event.which==13){
                                  
                                    $scope.messages.push($scope.message);
                                     }. Its not working.

Comment: I this case you can add a the form tag with ng-submit [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfmh5ryx/13/)

Comment: Other solution more useful is use a directive like this one: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lsconyer/bktpzgre/1/)